# Azure Publishing:a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/IISConfigurator.exe

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, visual-studio-2013, cloud

I am newbie in Microsoft Azure so I tried to create some easy chat for learning purpose. I found nice tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

I did everything as it is in this sites.

When I try to deploy project on server, I get error:

> The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: TestWebRole Invalid application runtime - a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/IISConfigurator.exe.

So I was looking for IISConfigurator.exe file in computer and I found it in that project. It's in path:

```
projectName/csx/Release/roles/projectName/base/x64/IISConfigurator.exe.
```

This file exists but it's on wrong place most likely.

I tried to put it all over the places in project, but nothing changed.
I tried to put it in system path, but this didn't help as well.

I am currently using Visual studio 2013 Community edition with admin rights.

Whole history for deploy:

```
16:40:22 - Applying Diagnostics extension.
16:40:42 - Preparing deployment for TestProject - 3. 4. 2015 16:40:14 with Subscription ID '9ca25534-0b9c-4b17-b259-e32d19977b7a' using Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
16:40:42 - Connecting...
16:40:42 - Verifying storage account 'wa2chatstorage'...
16:40:42 - Uploading Package...
16:40:48 - Creating...
16:41:19 - The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: TestWebRole Invalid application runtime - a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/IISConfigurator.exe.
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem. I am trying to use service bus, and it works locally, but when I attempt to deploy I get this same error. I currently have the Azure SDK 2.9. I am not sure why a powershell package would be required to do a deployment....

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue as well, but with a much scaled down version of what you're trying to do.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

I installed the latest SDK (2.7) and the PowerShell updates and it worked like a charm. Hope that helps!

Comment: I attempted to install the latest sdk, and It still did not work for me. a coworker was able to deploy my project fine from his laptop, so I am still at a loss why I cannot package locally

Comment: Different machines could be any number of issues. Have you checked package versioning to see if his machine has some different versions?

Comment: I installed the same azure sdk on our build server, and the packages are built fine. at a loss.

Comment: I've given up on trying to package locally, and I am now using TeamCity to build nugget packages that are deployed using octopus deploy. far more dependable anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in our TeamCity servers with that error message in it:

> Set-AzureDeployment : BadRequest : The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: [MyProject] Invalid application runtime - a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/IISConfigurator.exe.

The fix for me was to uninstall `Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools - v2.9.6` and `Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools - v2.9` from the build agent (which removed "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\runtimes\base\x64\IISConfigurator.exe"), and then reinstall the `Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools - v2.9` from the [Windows Azure SDK for .NET - 2.5 download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44938).